# System call open error

Tags: c, pipe, fork, system-calls

I have a homework about communication with pipe. I have 4 programs

1. main.c
2. prog1.c
3. prog2.c
4. prog3.c

main.c is parent and the others are child. I can run prog1.c and communicate with pipes from main.c. In prog2.c, I read a file name from pipe and use open() but prog2.c does not work after open().

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char ** envp){
    int pipefd[2];
    int pipes=pipe(pipefd);
    if(pipes< 0){
        perror("pipe hata");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    int f;
    f= fork();
                if(f==0){
                        i= execv("prog1",NULL);
            close(pipefd[1]);
                }
        else{
            wait(&i);
        }
    f= fork();
        int j;

        if(f== 0){
            j=execv("prog2", NULL);
            close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        else{
            wait(&j);
        }
    f= fork();
        int z;

        if(f== 0){
            z=execv("prog3", NULL);
            close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        else{
            wait(&z);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

prog2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char ** envp){
    printf("Prog2.c desin\n");
    int pipefd[2];
    char temp[1];

    printf("karakteri giriniz:");
    gets(temp);
    char *p = strchr(temp, '\n');
    if (p) *p = 0;

    char dosya[30];
    read(3, dosya,30);
    printf("Okunan: %s\n", dosya);

    char *dosyaIsmi;
    printf("Dosya Ismi:");
    scanf("%s",dosyaIsmi);
    printf("Dosya ismi(kullanıcıdan): %s\n", dosyaIsmi);

    const char *bosluk=" ";
    char newargv[32];
    char okunan[1];

    int fd=open(dosya, O_RDONLY, 0644);
    printf("fd\n");
    int fd3=open(dosyaIsmi, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_APPEND,        0644);  
    printf("fd3");

    int w=read(fd, okunan, 1);
    int byte=0;
    while(w> 0){
        printf("while\n");
        if(okunan[0]==' '){
            printf("if\n");
            lseek(fd,byte,SEEK_SET);
            write(fd3, temp, 1);            
        }
        else if(okunan[0]!=' '){
            printf("else if\n");
            write(fd3, okunan, 1);
        }
        byte++;
        w= read(fd, okunan, 1);
    }

    close(fd);
    close(fd3);
    write(4, dosya, 50);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: I see a few obvious problems. You do not call `dup2` to link the pipe descriptors to standard input for the child processes. You re-use the same pipe for all three child processes. You close one end of the pipe in the child process _after_ calling `execv`, but `execv` only returns on failure.

Comment: From where did you get file descriptor 3 for reading in prog2? read system call is a blocking system call that's why you are not able to get any thing from pipe because writer is not available.